# If I have a static value in an input field how can i pass it to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass this static value to my controller using Request.Form method using name attribute

```
<input type="text" value="Sunday" disabled  name="Day"/>
```

Comment: You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` because disabled fields are not submitted

Comment: still not submitted

Comment: not clear what you want, but you set disabled, the value can not pass to controller

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Day, new { @Value = "Sunday"})
```